# Wine price in a retail shop - Italy

Tags: budget, italy, alcohol, price

We are planing to go beach-camping to Italy.
Since We are trying to save as much money as possible, I would like to know what is the price range for wine in Italy.

Because when We went to France (I am from CZ and France is considered quite expensive), the wine was almost the same price as in CZ (starting from 3 EUR - well, but 3EUR wine > 3EUR CZ wine).

Italy has also its ups in white wine producing therefore I would consider unwise to take the wine from CZ if I can buy it there for almost the same price.

So what is the wine price in a retail shops in Italy?
Can You also add some approx. prices for other alcohol?

**Edit:**
I am looking for a decent quality (best price/quality ratio)

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is on topic here. Anyway you can buy wine starting for 1€ up to hundreds of euro.

Comment: Thank You for Your feedback. I am looking for a decent quality (best price/quality ratio). I hope that this narrows the question

Comment: I don't think it does since "decent quality" is highly subjective.

Comment: Ok, lets put it this way: In CZ, You have usualy 3 types of wine, wine below 2 EUR - It is quite impossible to produce a real wine below 2 EUR, therefore those wines are considered as bad. Then there is a 2-4 EUR. Usually most price/quality goes for 3 EUR. Above 4 EUR are whether overpriced or special wines.

Comment: Very subjective - there may be wines I like that others would consider too foul even for cooking, and vice versa. Voted to close.

Comment: @RoryAlsop, it is subjective but I guess that an objective answer could be given taking into considerations some profesional wine guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Italian. I would say that for a decent bottle of wine (0.75 liter) you will pay at least 8/euro in a market. Good white wines are muller thurgau, vermentino, Gewürztraminer (from trentino).

In a restaurant you should pay 4 euro for a glass and at least 15 for the bottle.

Of course this are price according to my definition of decent.